# Can we put a UIButton in a UIScrollView and vice versa in iPhone

Tags: iphone, uibutton

Can someone provide a code example for the given scenario?

Comment: You can put any uiview subclass instance into another, but why do you want to put a scrollview inside a button?

Comment: I like to to do it for the sake of doing it, just to find out how can i do it in iPhone?

Comment: If you want to find out how to do it, then asking the question defeats your object.

Comment: question shows no effort

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UIScrollView *scrollview = [[[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0F, 0.0F, 320.0F, 480.0F)] autorelease];
[self.view addSubview:scrollView];

UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType: UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[button setTitle:@"Title" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button setFrame:CGrectMake(0.0F, 0.0F, 50.0F, 50.0F)];
[scrollView addSubview:button];
```

If you have to add a subview to a UIButton then you would just to it in the opposite order:

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType: UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[button setTitle:@"Title" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button setFrame:CGrectMake(0.0F, 0.0F, 50.0F, 50.0F)];
[[self.view addSubview:button];
UIScrollView *scrollview = [[[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0F, 0.0F, 320.0F, 480.0F)] autorelease];
[button addSubview:scrollView];
```

But the `scrollview` will block the touches from the button unless you set `userInteractionEnabled` and `exclusiveTouch` properties to `NO` on the scrollview. But that would defeat the purpose of having a scrollview inside a button I think.

Comment: Fine!This is the code to set UIButton in UIScrollView. How to do it vice versa?What's the code?

Answer (score 0):

And if your button gets unclickable,then just check the content size of your view(self.view in case of IB). It should be greater than or equal to the size of the scrollView. In my case i was setting content size of scrollView as-

```
self.scrollView.contentSize=CGSizeMake(320,580);
```

and adding view as subview to the scrollView

```
[self.scrollView addSubview:self.view];
```

and didn't set the size of view. So that was my mistake. As default height of view is 480 
 in case of 3.5" retina display and 568 in case of 4" retina.

So i resolved this by setting content size of my view as-

```
self.view.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 700);
```

and adding this view as subview of scrollview.