# UIButton inside UIScrollView doesn't fire on tap

Tags: iphone

UIButton inside UIScrollView doesn't fire on tap. Please help resolve it.

```
// Add a button
UIButton *btn1 = [[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom] retain];
btn1.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 26, 18); 
btn1.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, 30.0, 30.0); 
[btn1 addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonClick1:) 
                     forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[scrollView addSubview:btn1];

- (void)buttonClick1:(id)sender {
    int dd = 4; 
}
```

Comment: Check the height or width of the scrollView to see if it is 0, and enable `clipSubview`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I found this stuff:

> But the scrollview will block the
>   touches from the button unless you set
>   userInteractionEnabled and
>   exclusiveTouch properties to NO on the
>   scrollview. But that would defeat the
>   purpose of having a scrollview inside
>   a button I think.

(See [Can we put a UIButton in a UIScrollView and vice versa in iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2833456/can-we-put-a-uibutton-in-a-uiscrollview-and-vice-versa-in-iphone))

But how to do it?

Say you have a UIScrollView *sv ... then

```
sv.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
sv.exclusiveTouch = YES;
```

I would also add

```
sv.canCancelContentTouches = YES;
sv.delaysContentTouches = YES;
```

Comment: canCancelContentTouches and delaysContentTouches are YES by default. ;)

Answer (score 14):

You must set content size of your view. That must be greater than or equal to the content size of scrollView.

Because default size of your view is 320 x 480 (3.5" retina) and 320 x 568 (4" retina). So increasing height of view as:

```
self.view.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 700);
```

Then adding this as the subview of your scrollView will get you to the solution.

Answer (score 10):

**OLD ANSWER:** All I had to do in iOS 7 was set

```
[_scrollView setDelaysContentTouches:NO];
```

**UPDATE:** After doing a little more research it appears that if your issue is that the `UIButton` click seems to only be called *sometimes*, then that is actually probably the desired behavior inside a `UIScrollView`. A `UIScrollView` uses the [delaysContentTouches](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiscrollview_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIScrollView/delaysContentTouches) property to automatically determine if the user was trying to scroll or trying to press a button inside the scroll view. I would assume it is best to not alter this behavior to default to `NO` since doing so will result in an inability to scroll if the user's finger is over a button.

Answer (score 6):

My structure is:

```
-View
--ScrollView
---ContainerView
```

and I am using snapkit. My issue was that my ContainerView actually had a height of 0.  I was able to notice this by setting `ClipsToBounds = true` on the ContainerView (nothing rendered after doing this as bounds had a height of 0).

**Any view out of the parent view's bounds will not receive the touch up inside events.**

My fix was to set the ContainerView left right and bottom anchors equal to the View and the top equal to the ScrollView (my ScrollView's top is offset from my root View's).

Answer (score 5):

I was facing this same problem, what i did was instead of adding the button to the container view, i've added it to the scroll view on top of the container view:

```
scrollView.insertSubview(buttonA, aboveSubview: containerView)
```

My structure was:

```
-View
--ScrollView
---ContainerView
```

I hope this could be of help to any one.

Comment: Would love to know why this is needed actually.. any explanation? Thanks for the tip, solved my problem.

Comment: @alasker , to be honest i do not have a explanation, but it makes me happy to know that it help you.

Answer (score 3):

This works for me in iOS 10

```
scrollView.delaysContentTouches = false
```

From Apple:

> A Boolean value that determines whether the scroll view delays the handling of touch-down gestures.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiscrollview/1619398-delayscontenttouches

Answer (score 0):

I tried all that you listed here. And also on the whole internet. But my buttons still couldn't be handled.

Finally, the only thing helped me. And I was able to keep "isUserInteractionEnabled" ON on the Scroll View.

So, how I fixed it:

1) Go to Storyboard

2) Connect ContentView and MainView between each other

[image: ContentView -> MainView Connect]

3) And select width/height equality

[image: ContentView & MainView Equality]

By the way, I also have views set up in the code (it doesn't work without prev steps for me).

```
// sizes
let width = self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.layoutFrame.width
mainView.frame = CGRect(x: 0 , y: 0, width: width, height: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.layoutFrame.height)
contentView.frame = CGRect(x: 0 , y: 0, width: width, height: 1000)
scrollView.frame = CGRect(x: 0 , y: 0, width: width, height: mainView.frame.height)

// constraints:
contentView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.widthAnchor).isActive = true
scrollView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.widthAnchor).isActive = true
```

Of course, this is not the solution like "just press two buttons and you'll solve your problem". The main reason was related to constraints & content size in my case. Just FYI, maybe it will help someone.